# BEM methodology for html template tag

Tags: html, css, bem, html-templates

I am building an website and trying to use template tag. And the template is below:

```
<template class="company-template">
<div>
  <img>
  <div></div>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
</div>
</template>
```

I want to add class for the elements in the template tag. However, as I know in BEM methology, the names of classes should be dependent to upper element. Should I write the codes just like below and modify or add classes depending on the upper element in JS?

```
<template class="company-template">
<div class="company-template__company">
  <img class="company-template__company__logo">
  <div class="company-template__company__description"></div>
  <button class="company-template__company__report">Report this company</button>
  <button class="company-template__company__chat">Chat with this company</button>
</div>
</template>
```

Or should I write codes depending on where the template will be used like below?

```
<template class="company-template">
<div class="search-result__company">
  <img class="search-result__company__logo">
  <div class="search-result__company__description"></div>
  <button class="search-result__company__report">Report this company</button>
  <button class="search-result__company__chat">Chat with this company</button>
</div>
</template>
```

In addition, if the template should be used in many other elements, how should classes be?

Comment: first one is correct.it will help mostly using `sass`.i wrote a demo which allows you to do nesting in CSS with BEM.https://codepen.io/umairfarooqlone/pen/yLjPMVp

Comment: read this aswell:https://css-tricks.com/using-sass-control-scope-bem-naming/